# Why use DELETE/POST instead of PUT for 'unfollowing/following' a user?

Tags: api-design, http-verbs

Referencing this API tutorial/explanation:
https://thinkster.io/tutorials/design-a-robust-json-api/getting-and-setting-user-data

The tutorial explains that to 'follow a user', you would use:

`POST /api/profiles/:username/follow`.

In order to 'unfollow a user', you would use:

`DELETE /api/profiles/:username/follow`.

The user Profile initially possesses the field `"following": false`.

I don't understand why the "following" field is being created/deleted (POST/DELETE) instead of updated from `true` to `false`. I feel as though I'm not grasping what's actually going on - are we not simply toggling the value of "following" between `true` and `false`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the database layer have to be implemented in a slightly more complex way than just having a boolean column for "following".

Given that you have three users, what would it mean that one of the users has `"following": true`? Is that user following something? That alone cannot mean that the user is following all other users, right?

The database layer probably consists of (at least) two different concepts: users and followings; users contain information about the user, and followings specify what users follow one another.

Say that we have two users:

```
[
  {"username": "jake"},
  {"username": "jane"}
]
```

And we want to say that Jane is following Jake, but not the other way around.

Then we need something to represent that concept. Let's call that a following:

```
{"follower": "jane", "followee": "jake"}
```

When the API talks about creating or deleting followings, this is probably what they imagine is getting created. That is why they use POST/DELETE instead of just PUT. They don't modify the user object, they create other objects that represent followings.

The reason they have a `"following": true/false` part in their JSON API response is because when you ask for information about a specific user, *as* one of the other users, you want to know if you as a user follows that specific user.

So, given the example above, when jane would ask for information about jake, at `GET /api/profiles/jake`, she would receive something like this:

```
{
  "profile": {
    "username": "jake",
    "bio": "...",
    "image": "...",
    "following": true
  }
}
```

However, when *jake* would ask for the profile information about jane, he would instead get this response:

```
{
  "profile": {
    "username": "jane",
    "bio": "...",
    "image": "...",
    "following": false
  }
}
```

So, the info they list as the API response is not what is actually stored in the database about this specific user, it also contains some information that is calculated based on who asked the question.

Comment: The database layer should be irrelevant to the design considerations of the API. The semantics of POST/DELETE vs. PUT are only relevant to the API layer.

Comment: I agree. I was only using that as an example, and maybe it was a clumsy one. A "following" in this case is a separate concept from a "user profile", and that is of course what the linked example tries to tell us as well. The question asks if we aren't just toggling a boolean value. That gave me the idea to try to explain one reason _why_ they speak of followings being created/deleted rather than just why the profile response would look different before and after a follow request was made.

Answer (score 0):

Using a microPUT would certainly be a reasonable alternative. I don't think anybody is going to be able to tell you why a random API tutorial made certain design decisions. It may be that they just needed a contrived example to use POST/DELETE.

Unless the author sees this question, I expect it's unanswerable. It's conceivable that they want to store meta information, such as the timestamp of the follow state change, but that would be unaffected by POST/DELETE vs. PUT.